# How to call python array in Javascript and use it for plotly

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7, plotly.js

I would like to plot many chart in my website but my array that I pass to HTML has about 10-12 data(or more).

This is the source of array:

```
        dataTrace = chartData.AvgTorque(sql)
        global graphJSON
        graphJSON = []
        for i in range(len(dataTrace)):
            graphJSONCreated = json.dumps(dataTrace[i], cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
            graphJSON.append(graphJSONCreated)
        return render_template('spc_chart.html', graphJSON=graphJSON)
```

My array that I pass to HTML look like this :

```
graphJSON = [dataTrace1, dataTrace2, dataTrace3, ... ]
```

I would like write code about this **but** I don't know how to use Javascript language. :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var graphs1 = {{graphJSON[0] | safe}};
    var graphs2 = {{graphJSON[1] | safe}};
    var graphs3 = {{graphJSON[2] | safe}};
    var graphs4 = {{graphJSON[3] | safe}};
    var graphs5 = {{graphJSON[4] | safe}};
    var graphs6 = {{graphJSON[5] | safe}};
    var graphs7 = {{graphJSON[6] | safe}};
    var graphs8 = {{graphJSON[7] | safe}};
    var graphs9 = {{graphJSON[8] | safe}};
    var graphs10 = {{graphJSON[9] | safe}};
    var graphs11 = {{graphJSON[10] | safe}};
    var graphs12 = {{graphJSON[11] | safe}};

    Plotly.plot('chart1',graphs1,{});        
    Plotly.plot('chart2',graphs2,{});        
    Plotly.plot('chart3',graphs3,{});        
    Plotly.plot('chart4',graphs4,{});        
    Plotly.plot('chart5',graphs5,{});        
    Plotly.plot('chart6',graphs6,{});        
    Plotly.plot('chart7',graphs7,{});        
    Plotly.plot('chart8',graphs8,{});        
    Plotly.plot('chart9',graphs9,{});        
    Plotly.plot('chart10',graphs10,{});        
    Plotly.plot('chart11',graphs11,{});        
    Plotly.plot('chart12',graphs12,{}); 
 </script>
```

**Note : I am not good in English may use the wrong words, or spell.**

Answer (score 0):

Before using in Javascript, try print the same within some html tag to check if your values are passed to html.

e.g, {{ graphJSON[0] | safe }}

If it is successfull, then try using the same value within **double quotes** inside javascript.

e.g, var graphs1 = "{{graphJSON[0] | safe}}";

Comment: I can do it by use this code 
>> let g1 = {{graphJSON | safe}};
>> for (i in g1){
                Plotly.plot('chartAvg'+i, g1[i].data, g1[i].layout || {});  
            }